# How do we really get the angle of a vector from the components?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Usually when people discuss getting the polar form of a vector $v$, they present the following two formulas:

$$\text{Magnitude}(v) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

$$\text{Angle}(v) = \arctan \left(\frac{y}{x} \right)$$

$$ \text{ Where } \space v = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$

I believe that this formula for the angle is only partially true. I think a better and more complete formula for the angle should be:

$$ \text{Angle}(v) = \begin{cases}
\arctan \left(\frac{y}{x} \right)  &; \space x \gt 0 \\
\pi +\arctan \left(\frac{y}{x} \right) &; \space x \lt 0 \\
{\begin{cases}
 \operatorname{sign}(y) \frac{\pi}{2}  &; y \neq 0 \\
\text{undefined} &; \space y = 0
\end{cases}} &; x = 0
\end{cases} $$

Is there some sort of way to simplify this or to better express this, or is this it?

Comment: The "[atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)" function was devised to help with this.

Comment: BTW: You can see `atan2` being used in the ["Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) section of Wikipedia's ["polar coordinate system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) entry. Who are these people you've been talking-to who "usually" just use `arctan`?

Comment: @Blue I see what you mean. Although the definition, in the link to Wikipedia you sent me, matches up with my definition, it does not seem as compact as my definition.

Comment: @Blue On stack exchange, on multiple websites when googling the same problem... these are the usual cases I am talking about. People almost never use this arctan2 definition you are talking about.

Comment: @Blue I have even come across the same partial definition in the textbooks assigned by my university and in lecture slides from Lecturers at other universities.

Comment: That's unfortunate. :/

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your sympathy. :)

Comment: I'll note that the computer algebra *Mathematica* uses a ["smart" `ArcTan` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html): when fed just one argument, it gives the regular inverse-tangent; when given both $x$ and $y$ arguments, it gives the quadrant-savvy version of the angle (equivalent to `atan2`).

Comment: After following the links in these comments, I see I could have saved myself some effort in writing my answer. (I basically rederived the atan2 formula given in Wikipedia. Note that it is not necessarily a merit of a formula that it can be written in fewer lines, just as fewer lines of code do not always make a better software program. My criteria would be that the formula gives good answers and is easy to understand.

Comment: @Gustav: For a *compact* formula, one can use simply $$\operatorname{sgn}_{+}y\,\cdot\,\arccos\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ where $\operatorname{sgn}_{+}$ is what I'll call the "*positively-biased* signum function", which returns $-1$ for negative arguments, and $+1$ for *non-negative* arguments. Note that the undefined-ness for $x=y=0$ is built-in. (This happens to be a slight refinement of a formula in the ["Converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) discussion on Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an answer in form of a *mathematical function definition,* using only functions that were in common use in undergraduate instruction fifty years ago, I do not think you can do much better than [the excellent answer by Rhys Hughes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080693/139123).
As noted in the answer, this is how mathematicians often define a function equivalent to yours in textbooks.
The only detail you might want to add is something to deal with the case $x = y = 0.$

Note that the formulas in that answer do not tell you *how* to find $\theta,$
but they *do* uniquely identify the output of the function for any possible input.
There is always some value of $\theta$ that will satisfy both equations when 
$x^2 + y^2 \neq 0,$ and there will never be more than one value of $\theta$ that satisfies both equations.

If you want a *formula to compute the angle* using only functions that were in common use in undergraduate instruction fifty years ago, I think the formula you wrote is close to the best you can get, though I would handle one or two cases a bit differently.

If you want a *nice way to represent your function* in other formulas, you can borrow the two-parameter arc tangent function that is defined in many software packages.
That is, define a function $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$
whose value is the angle of the vector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}.$
You can define $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ either in the style of the complex analysis textbooks described in the other answer, or you can define it in your style:

$$
\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) = \begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)      &  x \gt 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac yx\right) + \pi \quad &  x \lt 0, \ y \geq 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac yx\right) - \pi \quad &  x \lt 0, \ y < 0 \\
\frac\pi2   & x = 0,\ y > 0 \\
-\frac\pi2  & x = 0,\ y < 0 \\
\text{undefined} & x = 0,\ y = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

When this is implemented in software I think the "undefined" case usually returns $0.$

If you have to write formulas involving the direction angles of several two-dimensional vectors in terms of their components, then you might find the notation
$\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ convenient.

Comment: @Gustav Wow! I mean wow squared. You complain that "they" leave a little bit for you to figure out instead of giving you exactly what you want on a silver platter, then you speculate this is because _they_ are lazy? Wow. (_This_  is an example of what they mean by "irony". If you visit the_internet.com you can apply for a refund of the monry you paid...)

Comment: @Gustav Not frustrated at all, more amused.

Comment: @Gustav I understood the question. And I have no problem with anything you said about the answer - my comment had to do with you complaining about him being _lazy_. (_Do_ you know what the word "irony"  means?)

Comment: @David Thank you for pointing this out to me. It seems I have misunderstood Rhys's answer. I think it would be best if we deleted these comments as they have served their purpose in clearing out the misunderstanding we have had. I will then proceed to accept your answer.

Comment: No problem; I've deleted earlier comments.

Comment: @David K. Thank you.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich. Could you also remove your previous comments as they no longer serve any purpose?

Answer (score 4):

This looks very similar to complex numbers, where $\text{Magnitude}(v)$ is displayed by $|v|$ and $\text{Angle}(v)$ is written $\text{arg}(v)$. We have that $\arg(v)$ is the unique angle $\in (-\pi, \pi]$ where:

$$\cos\theta =\frac{x}{|v|}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
**and**
$$\sin\theta=\frac{y}{|v|}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: When working with only arctan, if we look at its graph, we can clearly see that it only gives values in the interval [$\frac{-\pi}{2}$ , $\frac{\pi}{2}$]. This only covers the first and fourth quadrants. So, in order to access the second and third quadrants, we need another definition. On top of that we need a definition for when the denomination in the usual definition would be zero, etc.

Comment: When the denominator equals to zero, the 2-norm or magnitude of the vector is 0 anyway. In other words, the 0 vector has no angle (Linear Algebra tells us that 0 is in the null space of any system fully described by the $R^2$).

Comment: @Joel When the denominator is zero, only one of the components is zero, not both. So no, the magnitude is not zero.

Comment: @Gustav you literally called $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ the magnitude in your question!

Comment: 2 comments back, I accidentally wrote denomination instead of denominator. With this I mean the value of x. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Rhys And your point is? We are discussing the angle, not the magnitude?

Comment: @Rhys If x is zero, but y is not, then the magnitude is |y| , not zero.

Comment: When $x=0$ we get $\cos \theta = 0$ and $\sin\theta= \pm 1$. It's easy to see $\theta=\pm \frac \pi2$, dependent on whether $y$ is positive or negative.

Comment: My definition includes that. That's what I was referring to from the beginning. I'm not the one with the misunderstanding here.

Comment: I think it's clear by now that this answer is based on a misunderstanding of what you _want._ Whether it was a misunderstanding of what you _asked_ is another matter, which could have been avoided if the question had said something like, "Please don't give me some kind of abstract mathematical definition; I want an algorithm that I can follow step by step." (A perfectly reasonable request!) But that's easy to say in hindsight.

Comment: @David I agree. I guess I could have included that in my question.

Comment: @Rhys In an earlier comment, which I have deleted, I stated that your answer does not solve the problem. I have realized, with the help of David K, that I was mistaken. Thank you for your answer.